# Need new pressure switch mechanism for a 3 phase compressor using a 220V AC Drive

Tags: design, mechanical, systems-engineering

I've bought a vintage Quincy 216 air compressor.  Actually there are duel Quincy 216's - each has a separate 3 phase motor.  One motor is 1.5 HP and the other motor is 2 HP.   The compressors share a common 80 gallon tank. These models of Quincy compressors have unloader valves.  The idea behind this duel compressor system is to always have at least one functional compressor at all times.

I wired these compressors to work with a GS2 AC Drive.  Only one compressor can operate at any given time using the one AC Drive.  Both compressors function well with the AC Drive.  The AC Drive has unique setting for each motor based on the data from the motor plates from each of the motors.

The compressors when purchased each included a electric/mechanical pressure switch.  These switches were likely wired to a mag-starter system that controlled the 3 phase on/off power to each compressor's electric motor.

The AC Drive is modern technology and I could not determine any way to properly integrate and use the existing pressure switches with the AC Drive.  This AC Drive is also used to power a 3 phase Bridgeport mill and or a 3 phase air-vac system.

What would be the best pressure switch mechanism to use with these compressors that are being powered by an AC Drive?

Comment: the ac drive doesn't have a starter circuit?

Comment: To use the compressors with the AC Drive, I press the "Run" button on the Drive.  I then watch the pressure gauge and then press the "Stop" button when the tank reaches about 90 psi.  To reach 90 psi from 0 psi takes about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  And it works perfectly.

The GS2, 2 HP VFD (aka Ac Drive) has a full set of configurations that allow the actual buttons and potentiometer on the face of the device to be jumped out.

Changing some configuration settings provides a way to make available a previously unused terminal strip on the device.

What that means is I was able to disable the ON button from the device and then use the terminal strip to jump the ON button.  This allows the terminal strip (jumping the ON button) to be used in a circuit with a low-voltage relay board.

The ProSense PSD 25 pressure switch provides the other necessary feature to make this circuit function.  This low voltage pressure switch outputs two signal wires: NO and NC.  The signal from the pressure switch get wired to the input voltage side of the relay board.  And the relay switch leg then controls the VFD's ON button.

When the air compressor needs air, the pressure switch's signal wire powers the relay, which opens the switch let to then activate the VFD's ON button.

When the air pressure reaches the upper set value (adjustable settings on the pressure switch), the pressure switch signal wire is de-energized.  The relay circuit leg closes.  The ON button is no longer jumped out.

When the air compressor needs air, the process repeats reliably.

Simple, cheap and the Quincy 216 works exactly the way a 3 phase compress should be functioning.  And it's being controlled by a 12 volt circuit.

See video on YouTube.   https://youtu.be/0ytmESaW9ws